# Which autocmd event to use to set the current directory to the directory of the file in the current window?

Tags: vim

The article at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file offers two suggestions.

- One that sets the `autochdir` option.

  ```
  set autochdir
  ```
- Another that uses `autocmd` on `BufEnter` event.

  ```
  autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
  ```

This question is about `autocmd` only.

On StackOverflow, there are other posts where the answers suggest using `autocmd BufEnter` to solve this problem.

- [How to set working/current directory in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288756/303363)
- [Change working directory to currently opened file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847796/303363)

But `lcd` is local to a window. The current directory for every window remains intact unless we explicitly change it. So I am curious why `autocmd BufEnter` is being suggested here. It feels excessive to me because `autocmd BufEnter` executes `lcd` every time I switch between windows, say with `Ctrl-w w`, even when the buffer in window I am switching to hasn't changed.

I think, it is sufficient to execute `lcd` whenever a buffer in a window changes, thus `autocmd BufwinEnter` is sufficient.

What can go wrong if `autocmd BufWinEnter` is used instead?

For example, let us consider the following alternate solution.

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * lcd %:p:h
```

Can you describe a scenario where the `autocmd BufEnter` command would do the right thing but `autocmd BufWinEnter` command would not?

Comment: Is there a reason, you don't want to set 'autochdir'?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am not trying to avoid `set autochdir`. I should  note that `:help autochdir` mentions, *"Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work"*, but that's not the reason why I want to avoid it. I haven't encountered any issues in the plugins I use due to `set autochdir`. I wanted this question to be about `autocmd BufEnter` because this workaround appearing in several places on the internet piqued me curiosity.

Comment: Ah okay. But first of all, I think plugins need to take of that and have to be fixed, if they can't take of of 'autochdir' and second of all, I think this information comes from a time, when that option was a little bit buggy. I remember issues with netrw, but that should be solved long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, I think the BufWinEnter autocommand might be the better approach, as it avoids resetting the directory every time you enter the buffer.

However, you might wonder, what happens, if the user changes the current directory for the current window. Using the BufEnter autocommand, this would get reset once you re-enter that particular buffer, while the BufWinEnter autocommand will not trigger. That might be a problem or not, but is something one should consider when deciding which autocommand to use.

BTW: I have never understood, why one would use such an autocommand instead of simply setting 'autochdir'. Because that's what this option is for. I think in the past, the autochdir option has had some bugs, but this has been fixed, as far as I know, so such workarounds are not needed anymore.

Comment: Because it's easier to ask about a (made-up) task of changing to file's directory than to explain e. g. that you want to cd to the root of the project of that file, or something else.