# Vim, exit at current files location

Tags: bash, vim, cwd

I run Vim and change my current location all the time via shortcuts.

Then when I exit Vim, I want to be in the directory of the file I was in, in the bash shell.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: For the most part you can't: a child process (vim) cannot modify the working directory of a parent process (the shell from which you started vim).

Comment: But can I have Vim return a string upon exit, which is the pwd the bash shall is to move itself to?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22949 A very good example on what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In multiprocess operating systems a subprocess cannot change anything in the parent process. But the parent process can cooperate so a subprocess can ask the parent process to do something for the subprocess. In your case on exit `vim` should return the last working directory and the shell should `cd` to it. I managed to implement cooperation this way:

In `~/.vimrc`:

```
call mkdir(expand('~/tmp/vim'), 'p') " create a directory $HOME/tmp/vim
autocmd VimLeave * call writefile([getcwd()], expand('~/tmp/vim/cwd')) " on exit write the CWD to the file
```

In `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
vim() {
    command vim "$@"
    rc=$?
    cd "`cat \"$HOME/tmp/vim/cwd\"`" && rm "$HOME/tmp/vim/cwd" &&
    return $rc
}
```

Comment: I took it a bit futher, named the function vim_cd_at_exit. Then if I want to vim, plus cd to where i exit i do "${EDITOR}_cd_at_exit". But if I don't want that i just run vim as before.

Comment: @john-jones Up to you. I don't use `cd`/`lcd` in `vim` at all so there is nowhere to `cd` to. I just wanted to solve an interesting challenge. :-)

Comment: Learn something from this. up voted!

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, Adapted/derived from @phd's answer.

Code for `vimrc`

```
augroup auto_cd_at_edit
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * if expand('%p:h') !~ getcwd() | silent! lcd %:p:h | endif
augroup END

" Pointing rm to `~/` gives me the chills! :-)
" Change the *path_name, file_name according to your own desire.
function! Vim_Cd_At_Exit()
  let l:file_name = 'cwd'
  let l:sub_pathname = 'vim_auto_cd'
  let l:path_name = getenv('TMPDIR') . '/' . l:sub_pathname
  call mkdir(l:path_name, 'p')
  call writefile(['cd -- '  .  shellescape(getcwd())], l:path_name . '/' . l:file_name)
endfunction

augroup Auto_Cd_After_Leave
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimLeave * call Vim_Cd_At_Exit()
augroup END
```

code for `~/.bashrc`

```
##: if `declare -p TMPDIR` has a value, you can skip this part
##: If not make sure your system has `/dev/shm` by default 
##: otherwise use another directory.
export TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-/dev/shm}

vim() {
  builtin local IFS rc path tmp_file
  tmp_file="$TMPDIR/vim_auto_cd/cwd"
  builtin command vim "$@"
  rc=$?
  if [[ -e "$tmp_file" && -f "$tmp_file" ]]; then
    IFS= builtin read -r path < "$tmp_file"
    [[ -n "$path" && "${path#cd -- }" != "'$PWD'" ]] && {
    builtin source "$tmp_file" || builtin return
    builtin printf '%s\n' "$path"
    ##: Uncomment the line below to delete the "$tmp_file"
    #builtin command rm "$tmp_file"
  }
  fi
  builtin return "$rc"
}
```

---

- On some system <kbd>vi</kbd> and <kbd>vim</kbd> points to say <kbd>/etc/alternatives</kbd> and the <kbd>bash</kbd> shell function name is just <kbd>vim</kbd>, so a quick way to avoid this functionality is just use <kbd>vi</kbd>. Either that or invoke/execute it with <kbd>command vim</kbd>, see: <kbd>help command</kbd>

---

Resources from above post:

- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file
- [Change working directory to currently opened file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847796/change-working-directory-to-currently-opened-file)
- [why-does-cd-not-change-the-directory/](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/why-does-cd-not-change-the-directory/)
- [I'm trying to write a script that will change directory (or set a variable), but after the script finishes, I'm back where I started (or my variable isn't set)!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060)