# .env file in golang project is not read-in when executing application through neovim

Tags: go, environment-variables, neovim, viper-go, .env

I recently started looking into Vim/NeoVim as a lightweight fast IDE. I followed some tutorials and managed to set it up with nvim-tree, treesitter, telescope etc. (all the basic stuff)
My Project opens fine with it, and I can use all the plugins I installed. It color codes my code files.

However when I execute :GoRun it prints { } (blank) environment variables from my .env file.

I wrote a small golang server that works fine when I execute it from vscode command line or just the terminal. I can use postman to make get and post requests and it returns valid json.

I am using the viper library to read the .env file.

I have searched through forums, asked chatgpt but I have not been able to find a solution to my problem.
I changed paths from relative to absolute for the .env file, I copied the .env file to my project root directory. I tried using :source and :ch command in neovim but nothing seems to work.

=====================================================================

Here is the error it throws, remember this code works through command line but not through neovim

```
:!'go' 'run' '/home/user/Projects/project1/cmd/main.go'  2>&1| tee /tmp/nvim.user1/rI2p6E/7
```

> [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.
>
> [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
>
> - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
> - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
>
> 2023/04/16 16:41:25 sql: unknown driver "" (forgotten import?)
> exit status 1

I need help.

Comment: Is your working directory the same from the CLI and within vim? You should not be using filename arguments with `go run`, which implies different package and module parameters than if you are building a package as a whole within a module.

Comment: Thanks for responding, that helped, "working directory" was the keyword in your answer. I did some search and came across this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847796/change-working-directory-to-currently-opened-file

In my ~/.config/nvim/.vimrc file I added  this setting ":set autochdir" saved it. 

Then I reopened vim at the root of my project and executed :pwd to see if it picked up my project directory as the root. 

I then updated the path to the .env file with the right number of directory changes "../.." and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just wanted to say ... Thank You for pointing me in the right direction.